# NotifyIcon not responsing to changes in its ContextMenu

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu, notifyicon

My (formless system-tray only) program has a `NotifyIcon` whose `ContextMenu` value must change dynamically on the running course of the program. The notification icon object is instantiated when the program starts as follows:

```
notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon()
{
    Icon = new Icon(@"C:\Users\basil\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Project Repository\Project Repository\Program Icon.ico"),
    Text = "My Program Name",
    Visible = false // Don't make it visible yet!
};
notifyIcon.ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
notifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems.AddRange(new MenuItem[] { new MenuItem("Host Service") { Index = 0 }, new MenuItem("Backup Configurations", new EventHandler(delegate { bckConf.Show(); })) { Index = 1 }, new MenuItem("Network Info", new EventHandler(delegate { new form_NetworkInfo().Show(); })) { Index = 2 }, new MenuItem("About", new EventHandler(delegate { new form_AboutUs().Show(); })) { Index = 3 }, new MenuItem("Exit", new EventHandler(delegate { TerminateProgram(ProgramTerminateReason.UserRequest); })) { Index = 4 } });
```

In order to change the `ContextMenu` of the `NotifyIcon`, a public method named `ChangeNotifyIconState` is created as menu items need to be changed as per the results generated by the objects of other classes in the program whose declaration is as follows: (Do disregard the variables of the "CurrentServiceState" data-type and note that the `NotifyIcon` object is declared as a class variable)

```
static public void ChangeNotifyIconState(CurrentServiceState state)
{
   notifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0].MenuItems.Clear(); // First clear all menu items of the to-be-updated block
   if (state==CurrentServiceState.Running)
   { // Service has started running; disable the start button and activate the stop and restart buttons
      notifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0].MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Start service", new EventHandler(delegate { HostServices.Start(); })) { Index = 0, Enabled = false });
      notifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0].MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Stop service", new EventHandler(delegate { HostServices.Stop(); })) { Index = 0, Enabled = true });
      notifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0].MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Restart service", new EventHandler(delegate { HostServices.Restart(); })) { Index = 0, Enabled = true });
   } else if (state==CurrentServiceState.Stopped)
   { // Service has stopped running; disable the stop and restart button and activate the start button
      notifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0].MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Start service", new EventHandler(delegate { HostServices.Start(); })) { Index = 0, Enabled = true });
      notifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0].MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Stop service", new EventHandler(delegate { HostServices.Stop(); })) { Index = 0, Enabled = false });
      notifyIcon.ContextMenu.MenuItems[0].MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Restart service", new EventHandler(delegate { HostServices.Restart(); })) { Index = 0, Enabled = false })};
   }
}
```

Here's the problem: when I call `ChangeNotifyIconState(CurrentServiceState.Running)`, the required `MenuItems` of the `ContextMenu` is not changed/updated. Can someone help me get rid of this unexpected behavior and explain me the cause behind it?

Thanks in advance.

EDITS:

I even marked the `NotifyIcon` object as a volatile object as I speculated that this was because of compiler caching. Turns out it wasn't as making the object `volatile` didn't solve the issue at hand.

Comment: I think you should create new ContextMenu and give it to notifyIcon.ContextMenu instead of doing this.

Comment: @S.Petrosov Do you mean create an entirely new ContextMenu instead of editing/replacing only the required MenuItem of the NotifyIcon?

Comment: yes, exactly that

Comment: anyway you are clearing ContextMenu before adding MenuItems

Comment: @S.Petrosov Hey, the solution you recommended does not solve the issue at hand. And sorry for late reply!

Comment: do I understood correct that this "notifyIcon" is not the one that is  Form's "this.notifyIcon"?

Comment: @S.Petrosov Any ideas?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144769/discussion-between-s-petrosov-and-hecate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example how you can create application without form and with `NotifyIcon` and how you can change `menuContextItems` of `NotifyIcon` for example on click event:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp5
{
    static class Program
    {

        private static Random rd = new Random();
        private static NotifyIcon notifyIcon;
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            NotifyIcon ni = new NotifyIcon(new System.ComponentModel.Container());
            ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();

            cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("First", Click));
            cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Second", Click));
            cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Third", Click));
            cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Exit", (obj,e)=> { Application.Exit(); }));
            ni.Icon = new Icon(@"c:\Users\Admin\Desktop\img.ico");
            ni.Text = "Form1 (NotifyIcon example)";
            ni.ContextMenu = cm;
            ni.Visible = true;
            notifyIcon = ni;
            Application.Run();

        }

        public static bool  SomeCondition()
        {
            return (rd.Next(0, 9999) % 2) == 1;
        }

        public static void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (SomeCondition())
            {
                ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
                cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Fourth", Click));
                cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Fifth", Click));
                cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Sixth", Click));
                cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Exit", (obj, args) => { Application.Exit(); }));
                notifyIcon.ContextMenu = cm;
            }
            else
            {
                ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
                cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Third", Click));
                cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Sixth", Click));
                cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Fourth", Click));
                cm.MenuItems.Add(new MenuItem("Exit", (obj, args) => { Application.Exit(); }));
                notifyIcon.ContextMenu = cm;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here are screenshots how this will be:

At application start the notifyIcon will appear and menu will be the following:
[image]

As my condition is returning random `true` or `false` after `click` on any `menuItem` except "Exit" will work `Click event handler` and change `menucontext`. As a result you will get menu like one of this:
[image]

or

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help and effort!